# How do i rewrite a url with a question mark

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a URL in Apache:

```
www.example.com/servlet/ESGOrderNewLoginServlet?evt_uid=1832
```

to

```
www.example.com/servlet/ESGOrderNewLoginServlet?evt_uid=1163
```

I've tried the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^servlet/ESGOrderNewLoginServlet\?evt_uid=1832 /servlet/ESGOrderNewLoginServlet?evt_uid=1163 [L,R]
```

I've also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} evt_uid=1832$
RewriteRule ^servlet/ESGOrderNewLoginServlet$ /servlet/ESGOrderNewLoginServlet?evt_uid=1163 [L,R]
```

and other variations which don't seem to work. I'm stumped, I've never done this before. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can't manipulate querystring in RewriteRule's pattern that is why your first attempt failed. Your second attempt looks ok and the rule should work as is. Are you sure mod-rewrite is enabled on your server?

Comment: yes, mod-rewrite is enabled. There are other rewrites that work. If I take the ^servlet/ out and just use ^ESGOrderNewLoginServlet$ it rewrites if I go to www.myurl.com/ESGOrderNewLoginServlet?evt_uid=1832  -  I don't know what's wrong with /servlet/

Comment: maybe servlet/ is affected by one of the already existing rules?

Comment: Please include your `.htaccess` file, it sounds like you might have a conflict. Just to clarify, you are _redirecting_, not _rewriting_ the URL in your directives.

Comment: we don't use .htaccess all of the rewrites are in the httpd.conf file. I put this rewrite near the top, so it shouldn't hit any other rules because i used [L] is that accurate ?     Is it possible that tomcat takes over when the url hits /servlet/  ?  It just won't match anything with /servlet/...

Comment: Then why did you tag your question `.htaccess`?! mod_rewrite directives work differently, depending on the _context_ in which they are used. In [what _context_](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) are these directives in your server config? In a _directory_ context the `L` flag does not necessarily prevent the following directives from being processed. Also, different modules execute independently, regardless of the apparent order of the directives in the config file.

Comment: Ok sorry, i thought .htaccess worked the same. The Rewrites are inside the <directory>, above it is where mod_jk is and inside it is a JkMount /servlet/* pointing to worker1 which has the following:          worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
#worker.worker1.connection_pool_timeout=600

Comment: I'm guessing /servlet in JkMount takes over. I tried to use [PT] at the end of my rewrite, but it still doesn't work.